# Exclude dashboard-builder-bom dependency from Knowledgebase in drools via maven

Tags: maven, drools

I have tried to exclude the package, but it is still trying to download dashboard-builder-bom. What am I doing wrong?

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.dashboard-builder</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dashboard-builder-bom</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

> Failed to collect dependencies at org.drools:drools-core:jar:6.5.0.Final: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.drools:drools-core:jar:6.5.0.Final: Could not find artifact org.jboss.dashboard-builder:dashboard-builder-bom:pom:6.5.0.Final in (artifact repo)

Comment: That's a bill of materials, not a package. It basically explains what versions of stuff to use.